# Manipulate CSS of child theme with Javascript (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to implement 3 Buttons in my website that should change the font size when clicked.

the HTML is going to look something likes

```
<div class='normal_font_size'>ill put some image here</div>
<div class='medium_font_size'>ill put some image here</div>
<div class='big_font_size'>ill put some image here</div>
```

this is the CSS that should be changed in the child theme(?)(lets say normal= 100%, medium= 150, big= 200%)

```
html { font-size: 100% }
```

I use a child theme of this theme: http://davidakennedy.com/accessible-zen/
I have a style.css in my child theme folder

I would put the HTML in the page.php of the child theme folder so it is just beneath the my header, is that best practice?

How do I manipulate the CSS?

My first question would be where to put the Java-Code so the CSS gets actually affected because I tried to make some basic manipulations and I didn't get any changes done so far...

*answer: I put the code inside a custom-script.js in my childtheme/js directory and I enqueue that script in my functions.php in my childtheme directory.
From there I can use the code to manipulate the css inside my childtheme's custom.css

My current understanding of JavaScript & Jquery probably is on the same lvl as your chinese (most likely).
But I want to improve! That's why I am here

Thank's for your time!

*Update

@Eduardo Your Code unfortunately doesn't work for me, maybe I put it at the wrong spot... as I told you I am really just getting started with everything that's not HTML or CSS.

this is how my custom-script.js of my child theme is enqueued (correctly, jQuery library is loading) and I put your code inside of that custom-script.js. You said I should put it in the main .js but so far that is the only .js in my child theme directory...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_scripts' );
function menu_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:

This code works fine for me now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','1000%');
  });
});
```

looks like the $-signs caused trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `style.css` in the root directory of your child-theme.
Add all of your style there.

If the content still isn't being picked up (although it should), add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

Modify ifrequired, of course.

EDIT.
One possible reason your js is not working is because it's not recognizing the `$`. You have to remember Wordpress runs jQuery in no conflict mode.
If you use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});
```

it will probably work just fine.
If you really want to keep the `$` notation however, wrap it like this:

```
(function($) {

    // Inside here $ = jQuery
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello George I already use a style.css in my child theme for modifications and it is working fine, I put the code inside of there. 
I think the problem is with the jQuery or Java Code or it's files

Comment: Oh I see now. Can you print any errors you get in the console. Also, would it be possible to see your .js file?

Comment: Hey George it's working now, I will now try to create the 3 buttons with the according function, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, Java and Javascript are not the same language.

Now, you probably can just use jquery to select your buttons. For example:

```
In your page.php or index.php:
<button class="my-button">Small Font</button>
```

Next you want to call that button onclick with jquery:

```
On your main.js
 $(document).ready(function() {

        //storing your button in var, so you can reference it
        var mybutton = $(".my-button");

        //when you click the button, something happens
        mybutton.on('click', function() {

        //do something here (consider using jquery's .css functions to alter the font size)

        }

    });
```

Additionally, you can also add classes to your style.css and then use jquery's .addClass() to assing your css classes wherever you would like the fonts to grow.

You asked how to alter the html tag to increase the font globally. First off, you don't want to tag the html tag, you just want to tag the body. Make sure you know the fundamental differences between html, head, and body.

So this is how on the click of a button, you would make all the font inside of the body of your document, increase in 100%.

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', function() {

    $('body').css('font-size','100%');

}
```

Comment: Thank you Eduardo. 
Do you know how I alter the font-size of this Element using jquery?
html { font-size: 100%}

Comment: I tried some variations but nothing works, not even if I copy your example from jsfiddle 1:1.
I am really a total beginner when it comes to jquery, Java and all that stuff so I can guess the problem must be somewhere else.
I edited the post, please check if you got the patience :)

Comment: The $ seems to have caused some issues, George's code worked fine. Thanks anyway Eduardo

Comment: $ is short for JQuery in the code. Try to learn about using $(this) in jQuery and how storing your elements in variables save a lot of processing to the browser. This is because everytime you use JQuery or $ (again, both are the same thing) jquery is actually going through all of your document again to find the same element you may have used before. There a million other ways to be more efficient with jQuery, so make sure you start out writing good efficient code, and not pick up any bad habits.

Comment: I want to write effecient code! How could I write my code below more efficiently while it keeps working? Appearently the $ doesn't work that way because Wordpress runs jQuery in no conflict mode as George described

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys its working perfectly fine now. Thanks everybody.

This is my code, is it fine like this or could I cut it somehow?

Next problem is going to be to save it in a cookie ...

HTML:

```
<button class='body_standard_font_size'>Standard</button>
<button class='body_medium_font_size'>medium</button>
<button class='body_big_font_size'>big</button>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_standard_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','100%');
});
});
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_medium_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','150%');
});
});
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.body_big_font_size').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('body').css('font-size','200%');
});
});
```